# how to skip each 2 index of 1D array while iterating in for loop

Tags: arrays, c, loops, image-processing

following image is the 1D array data i want iterate, i want to iterate 2 index and skip 2 index and repeat continuously until the end of data

[image]

how do i skip 2 index each of 1D array within for loop to fetch value of yellow rectangular (1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14) and implemented it on following code

```
  for(int i = 0; i < posBuffer.pixels.length; i++){
if(blue(posBuffer.pixels[i]) > 0){
  count++;
 avg.add(red(posBuffer.pixels[i]) / 255.0, green(posBuffer.pixels[i]) / 255.0);
}
```

}

Comment: First, a note: array indices are 0-based which means your example should be `0,1,4,5, 8,9, ...`. Next, look at the pattern: each block starts with a multiple of 4: 0,4,8,12 - so use a loop to go from block to block: `for(int i = 0; i < length; i += 4)`. Then, inside each block just get the number of consecutive indices you need. Assuming 2 is an example here and you want to be flexible just use an inner loop: `for(int j = i; j < i + 2; j++)` or just use `for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)` and do `index = i + j` in the loop body.

Comment: @Thomas try as you said and get errors ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147450880     for(int i = 0; i < posBuffer.pixels.length ; i+=640){
    for(int j = i; j < i + 100; j++)   
     i = i + j;
   if(blue(posBuffer.pixels[i]) > 0){
  count++;
  avg.add(red(posBuffer.pixels[i]) / 255.0, green(posBuffer.pixels[i]) / 255.0);
   }
} btw its related to several my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74099195/how-to-change-one-dimensional-for-loop-to-be-two-dimension-for-loop

Comment: @Thomas and this  https://discourse.processing.org/t/realtime-image-processing-using-thread-or-class-extending-thread/30304/37 my web cam led indicator is on but some how its stuck somewhere, i found ArrayindexOutOfBoundsException: 1 in Java  but don't understand https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/02/solving-javalangarrayindexoutofboundsexception-0-1-2-in-java.html#axzz7iAO0XhEM

Comment: As I already commented in the other question: step through your code with a debugger and check the index values and array lengths. Array indices must be in the range 0 to length-1 and anything outside that range will give the ArrayindexOutOfBoundsException. So if it gives the exception for index 1 then the array either has just 1 element or none at all (i.e. length 0 or 1). -2147450880 indicates you have some overflow which might mean `posBuffer.pixels.length` is very large or you're doing it wrong. In any case: when asking about exceptions, include the stack trace.